# If $p>2$ is a prime number, Prove that $U(p^k) $ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

(i) If $p>2$ is a prime number, Prove that $U(p^k)  $ is cyclic

(ii) Prove that $U(p^n) \thickapprox Z_{(p^n -p^{n-1}) }$

**Solution** : If I prove that if $U(p^k)  $ is cyclic, then, we know that Any cyclic group of order $n$ is isomorphic to group $Z_n$, then, $U(p^n) \thickapprox Z_{\phi{(p^n)}} = Z_{(p^n -p^{n-1}) }$

So, we need to prove that If $p>2$ is a prime number, then $U(p^k)  $ is cyclic

$|U(p^k)  | =  \phi{(p^k)} = p^k-p^{k-1}$

So, we need an element $a \in U(p^k)$ such that $a^{ \phi{(p^k)} }=  U(p^k)$

I have little clue how this can be proved. Help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The usual proof, that goes back to Gauss, consits of the following steps. (i) if $a$ is a primitive root of $p$, and $a$ does not have order $p-1$ modulo $p^2$, then $a$ is a primitive root of $p^2$; (ii) otherwise, $a+p$ is a primitive root of $p^2$; (iii) if $a$ is a primitive root of $p^2$, then $a$ is a primitive root of $p^k$ for all $k\ge 2$. None of the steps is terribly long, but a detailed proof takes a while.

Comment: You can find the proof in every book about Elementary Number Theory. (for example: Ireland, Rosen - A classical introduction to modern number theory has an entire chapter dedicated to it)

Comment: Okay thank you . I think Gallian must have skipped the proof owing to this reason that the proof is quite long.

Comment: In [this handout](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjZv7yU_u-BAxV_wAIHHWuoD3wQFnoECAkQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whitman.edu%2Fdocuments%2FAcademics%2FMathematics%2FSeniorProject_BrianSloan.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3tbm_oYCMtNebGAaHBPpzb&opi=89978449), the detailed solution plus some other relating things are available.